# Showing progress of ZipFiles Class

Tags: vb.net, zip, progress-bar

I was wondering, how can I get the percentage of this being done, so I can display it on a progress bar?

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:\temp\folder", "C:\temp\folder.zip")
```

and also

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("C:\temp\folder.zip", "C:\temp\folder")
```

Comment: Same question, for C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430559/progress-bar-not-available-for-zipfile-how-to-give-feedback-when-program-seems

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while checking for related questions for [the identical question, asked for C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430559/progress-bar-not-available-for-zipfile-how-to-give-feedback-when-program-seems). It is true that the .NET static `ZipFile` class does not offer progress reporting. However, it is not hard to do using the `ZipArchive` implementation, available since earlier versions of .NET.

The key is to use a `Stream` wrapper that will report bytes read and written, and insert that in the data pipeline while creating or extracting the archive.

I wrote a version in C# for an answer to the other question, and since I didn't find any VB.NET examples, figured it would be helpful to include a VB.NET version on this question.

*(Arguably, I could include both examples in a single answer and propose closing one of the questions as a duplicate of the other. But since it's doubtful the close vote would result in an actual closure, the connection between the two questions would not be as obvious as it should be. I think for best visibility to future users trying to find the solution appropriate for their needs, leaving this as two different questions is better.)*

The foundation of the solution is the `Stream` wrapper class:

**StreamWithProgress.vb**

```vb
Imports System.IO

Public Class StreamWithProgress
    Inherits Stream

    ' NOTE For illustration purposes. For production code, one would want To
    ' override *all* of the virtual methods, delegating to the base _stream object,
    ' to ensure performance optimizations in the base _stream object aren't
    ' bypassed.

    Private ReadOnly _stream As Stream
    Private ReadOnly _readProgress As IProgress(Of Integer)
    Private ReadOnly _writeProgress As IProgress(Of Integer)

    Public Sub New(Stream As Stream, readProgress As IProgress(Of Integer), writeProgress As IProgress(Of Integer))
        _stream = Stream
        _readProgress = readProgress
        _writeProgress = writeProgress
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanRead As Boolean
        Get
            Return _stream.CanRead
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanSeek As Boolean
        Get
            Return _stream.CanSeek
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanWrite As Boolean
        Get
            Return _stream.CanWrite
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Length As Long
        Get
            Return _stream.Length
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Property Position As Long
        Get
            Return _stream.Position
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
            _stream.Position = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub Flush()
        _stream.Flush()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub SetLength(value As Long)
        _stream.SetLength(value)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function Seek(offset As Long, origin As SeekOrigin) As Long
        Return _stream.Seek(offset, origin)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub Write(buffer() As Byte, offset As Integer, count As Integer)
        _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count)
        _writeProgress?.Report(count)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function Read(buffer() As Byte, offset As Integer, count As Integer) As Integer
        Dim bytesRead As Integer = _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count)

        _readProgress?.Report(bytesRead)
        Return bytesRead
    End Function
End Class
```

The wrapper class can be used to implement progress-aware versions of the `ZipFile` static methods:

**ZipFileWithProgress.vb**

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

NotInheritable Class ZipFileWithProgress

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub CreateFromDirectory(
        sourceDirectoryName As String,
        destinationArchiveFileName As String,
        progress As IProgress(Of Double))

        sourceDirectoryName = Path.GetFullPath(sourceDirectoryName)

        Dim sourceFiles As FileInfo() = New DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectoryName).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim totalBytes As Double = sourceFiles.Sum(Function(f) f.Length)
        Dim currentBytes As Long = 0

        Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(destinationArchiveFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
            For Each fileInfo As FileInfo In sourceFiles
                ' NOTE: naive method To Get Sub-path from file name, relative to
                ' input directory. Production code should be more robust than this.
                ' Either use Path class Or similar to parse directory separators And
                ' reconstruct output file name, Or change this entire method to be
                ' recursive so that it can follow the sub-directories And include them
                ' in the entry name as they are processed.
                Dim entryName As String = fileInfo.FullName.Substring(sourceDirectoryName.Length + 1)
                Dim entry As ZipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(entryName)

                entry.LastWriteTime = fileInfo.LastWriteTime

                Using inputStream As Stream = File.OpenRead(fileInfo.FullName)
                    Using outputStream As Stream = entry.Open()
                        Dim progressStream As Stream = New StreamWithProgress(inputStream,
                            New BasicProgress(Of Integer)(
                                Sub(i)
                                    currentBytes += i
                                    progress.Report(currentBytes / totalBytes)
                                End Sub), Nothing)

                        progressStream.CopyTo(outputStream)
                    End Using
                End Using
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub ExtractToDirectory(
        sourceArchiveFileName As String,
        destinationDirectoryName As String,
        progress As IProgress(Of Double))

        Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(sourceArchiveFileName)
            Dim totalBytes As Double = archive.Entries.Sum(Function(e) e.Length)
            Dim currentBytes As Long = 0

            For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries
                Dim fileName As String = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryName, entry.FullName)

                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName))
                Using inputStream As Stream = entry.Open()
                    Using outputStream As Stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName)
                        Dim progressStream As Stream = New StreamWithProgress(outputStream, Nothing,
                            New BasicProgress(Of Integer)(
                                Sub(i)
                                    currentBytes += i
                                    progress.Report(currentBytes / totalBytes)
                                End Sub))

                        inputStream.CopyTo(progressStream)
                    End Using
                End Using

                File.SetLastWriteTime(fileName, entry.LastWriteTime.LocalDateTime)
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

The .NET built-in implementation of `IProgress(Of T)` is intended for use in contexts where there is a UI thread where progress reporting events should be raised. As such, when used in a console program, like which I used to test this code, it will default to using the thread pool to raise the events, allowing for the possibility of out-of-order reports. To address this, the above uses a simpler implementation of `IProgress(Of T)`, one that simply invokes the handler directly and synchronously.

**BasicProgress.vb**

```vb
Class BasicProgress(Of T)
    Implements IProgress(Of T)

    Private ReadOnly _handler As Action(Of T)

    Public Sub New(handler As Action(Of T))
        _handler = handler
    End Sub

    Private Sub Report(value As T) Implements IProgress(Of T).Report
        _handler(value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And naturally, it's useful to have an example with which to test and demonstrate the code.

**Module1.vb**

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim sourceDirectory As String = args(0),
            archive As String = args(1),
            archiveDirectory As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPath(archive)),
            unpackDirectoryName As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

        File.Delete(archive)
        ZipFileWithProgress.CreateFromDirectory(sourceDirectory, archive,
            New BasicProgress(Of Double)(
                Sub(p)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{p:P2} archiving complete")
                End Sub))

        ZipFileWithProgress.ExtractToDirectory(archive, unpackDirectoryName,
            New BasicProgress(Of Double)(
                Sub(p)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{p:P0} extracting complete")
                End Sub))
    End Sub

End Module
```

Additional notes regarding this implementation can be found in [my answer to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42436311).

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt have any events or callbacks that you can use to report progress. Simply means **you cant** with the .Net version. If you used the 7-Zip library you can do this easily.

Comment: Is there a way I can use the 7-Zip library without the user having or downloading a DLL file?

Comment: The zip you create with 7-Zip should be able to open with Windows in most cases. A user doesnt have to download anything, you will include the library in your project.

Comment: Ok. I did some research and could find an example of compressing, but not extracting. Can you please provide a quick example of both and how to calculate the percentage? I couldn't find anything on getting the percentage done, either. There doesn't seem to be any proper tutorials on their website.